# jQuery: enabling/disabling datepicker

Tags: jquery, datepicker

In my php-file, I want to use the jQuery Datepicker.

When my file loads, I create the Datepicker disabled.

Then, when a special field in my php-file (it is a form) is filled, I want to enable the Datepicker.

So, initially my Datepicker looks like this:

```
$("#from").datepicker({
    showOn: "both",
    buttonImage: "calendar.gif",
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    buttonText: "Kalender",
    showAnim: "drop",
    dateFormat: "dd.mm.yy",
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    showButtonPanel: true,
    showWeek: true,
    firstDay: 1,
    dayNamesMin: ["So", "Mo", "Di", "Mi", "Do", "Fr", "Sa"],
    weekHeader: "KW",
    disabled: true,
    onClose: function(selectedDate) {
        $("#to").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
    }
});
```

This works just fine, no problem so far. The problem comes, when I want to disable the field.

If a special field is filled, I call `$("#from").datepicker('enable');`

This also works fine, BUT now I want to disable it again if the special field I mentioned it empty again.

Then I use `$("#from").datepicker('disable');` and the field itself is grayed, but I can still use the field to enter values, the calender pops up and even the calender-image next to the box is clickable.

Anyone has an idea why this is the case? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

`$("#from").datepicker('disable');` should work, but you can also try this:

```
$( "#from" ).datepicker( "option", "disabled", true );
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work
Even though I don't understand why it doesn't work.
The .prop-idea that Shaun Hare mentioned works though

Comment: I never used that before, just tried it out. Somehow it doesn't seem to include jQuery-FW though, even though I clicked it on "Frameworks & Extensions"..Sorry :-(

Comment: Here http://jsfiddle.net/VMzLG/ I put together a simple demo, surprisingly the only way I got it to successfully disable was by using the code from your question

Comment: That is strange....your demo shows exactly how I thought it would work.
But on my local code, it doesn't work.
I have a meeting soon, I will look into this after that.
Might be tomorrow though...

Comment: I found it out finally!
It is an internal fault....we use special form-elements and after I disabled the item, I gave the class a new name...BUT I forgot to append a "hasDatepicker" to the new class-name.
I am sorry everyone, but all your hints helped me to solve the mystery.
Thank you, everyone!! :-)

Comment: @AK Glad to hear you sorted things out :) next time though you should include all relevant code in your question so we can help you pinpoint the issue more easily

Comment: You are right! I am a bit ashamed of myself that I made such a emberassing mistake. But I am glad you all are such a nice community. Thank you all again! :-)

Comment: `$("#from").datepicker('disable');
$("#from").datepicker('enable');` worked for me. the other one `$( "#from" ).datepicker( "option", "disabled", true );` doesn't work.

Comment: If you're trying to disable all controls inside a div of which this is one, you may need to disable the datepicker first and then the remainder of the controls.

Comment: @koala_dev Hi, the way `$('selector').datepicker('disable')` I can't find where this is documented. Can you help me?

Comment: Warning: At least in jQuery-UI 1.9.0 (which I'm still having to use in a project), the *documentation* is wrong. `datepicker('option', 'disabled', true/false)` does not work; instead you need to use direct methods `datepicker('disable')` and `datepicker('enable')`.

Answer (score 17):

Also set the field to disabled when you disable the datePicker e.g

```
$("input").prop('disabled', true);
```

To stop the image being clickable you could unbind the click event on that

```
$('img#<id or class ref>').unbind('click');
```

Comment: thank you, that helped disabling the field.
strange that `document.getElementsByName('from')[0].readOnly = 'readonly'` didn't work (disabled neither), but .prop as you mentioned works fine!
However, the image is still clickable and pops up the datepicker.
Is there a way to gray out the image as well?
I didn't know the .prop-function....I am quite new to jQuery.
However, the image is still clickable and brings up the datepicker.
Is there a way to gray it out as well?

Comment: you could just unbind the click event on it - .off ?

Comment: I tried `$("#from").off();`, which is said to remove all event handlers, but it made not difference

Answer (score 15):

try

```
$("#from").datepicker().datepicker('disable');
```

Comment: but while using this resets my existing datepicker to the default one. any way to maintain my old datepicker properties

Answer (score 7):

```
$("#nicIssuedDate").prop('disabled', true);
```

This is works 100% with **bootstrap Datepicker**

Comment: kudos to write bootstrap Datepicker!

Answer (score 6):

simply use the following code

```
$("#from").datepicker({
 showOn: "off"
});
```

it will not show the display of datepicker

Comment: Simply grate answer...In my case i dont want to disable my date picker because i used its value into form submit...plus safari and firefox does not stop query date picker from display as it does into Chrome so i found this answer is useful...thank you

Answer (score 3):

I am also having This Error!

Then i change this

```
$("#from").datepicker('disable');
```

to This

```
$("#from").datepicker("disable");
```

mistake : single and double quotes..

Now its Work fine for me..

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#ElementID').unbind('focus');
```

did the trick for me !!

Comment: An explanation for why it worked for you would be helpful to the poster.

Answer (score 3):

This works for me on toggling enable and disable datepicker of JQuery:

```
if (condition) {
          $('#ElementID').datepicker(); //Enable datepicker                   
} else {
         //Disable datepicker without the ability to enter any character on text input
          $('#ElementID').datepicker('destroy');
          $('#ElementID').attr('readonly', true); }
```

I don't know why but when I use **enable/disable** in datepicker options, it doesn't behave the way it should be. It only works after you enable and disable it, but once you disable it, it doesn't enable again after, so the code above works perfectly fine for me:

```
if (condition) {
      $('#ElementID').datepicker('enable'); //Enable datepicker                   
} else {
      //Disable datepicker but I cannot enable it again once it goes through this condition
      $('#ElementID').datepicker('disable');  }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me

```
$("#from").attr("disabled", true);
```

Comment: This has some ugly side effects: If you try to serialize your form those disabled fields are ignored.

Answer (score 1):

I have a single-page app in our company intranet where certain date fields need to be "blocked" under certain circumstances. Those date fields have a *datepicker* binding.

Making the fields read-only wasn't enough to block the fields, as *datepicker* still triggers when the field receives focus.

Disabling the field (or disabling *datepicker*) have side effects with *serialize()* or *serializeArray()*.

One of the options was to unbind *datepicker* from those fields and making them "normal" fields. But one easiest solution is to make the field (or fields) read-only and to avoid datepicker from acting when receive focus.

```
$('#datefield').attr('readonly',true).datepicker("option", "showOn", "off");
```

Answer (score 1):

Datepicker is disabled automatically when the input text field is made disabled or readOnly:

```
$j("#" + CSS.escape("${status.expression}")).datepicker({
    showOn: "both",
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    buttonImage: "<c:url value="/static/js/jquery/1.12.1/images/calendar.gif"/>",
    dateFormat: "yymmdd",
    beforeShow: function(o, o2) {
    var ret = $j("#" + CSS.escape("${status.expression}")).prop("disabled")
        || $j("#" + CSS.escape("${status.expression}")).prop("readOnly");

    if (ret){
        return false;
    }

    return o2;
}
});
```

Comment: Work for me with a sligthly modification: change $j("#" + CSS.escape("${status.expression}")) to $(o).

Answer (score 1):

For those who are using 2012-2013 versions, you can do this:

```
$('#from').datepicker('remove');
```

Then to enable it back:

```
$('#from').datepicker('add');
```

Here's the [documentation](https://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/).

Answer (score 0):

Well You can remove datepicker by simply remove `hasDatepicker` class from input.

**Code**

```
$( "#from" ).removeClass('hasDatepicker')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to toggle disabled with jQuery Datepicker and with any other form element also.

```js
/***
  *This is the toggle disabled function Start
  *
  **/
(function($) {
  $.fn.toggleDisabled = function() {
    return this.each(function() {
      this.disabled = !this.disabled;
      if ($(this).datepicker("option", "disabled")) {
        $(this).datepicker("option", "disabled", false);
      } else {
        $(this).datepicker("option", "disabled", true);
      }

    });
  };
})(jQuery);

/***
  *This is the toggle disabled function Start
  *Below is the implementation of the same
  **/

$(".filtertype").click(function() {
  $(".filtertypeinput").toggleDisabled();
});

/***
  *Implementation end
  *
  **/

$("#from").datepicker({
  showOn: "button",
  buttonImage: "http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/datepicker/images/calendar.gif",
  buttonImageOnly: true,
  buttonText: "Select date",
  defaultDate: "+1w",
  changeMonth: true,
  changeYear: true,
  numberOfMonths: 1,
  onClose: function(selectedDate) {
    $("#to").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
  }
});
$("#to").datepicker({
  showOn: "button",
  buttonImage: "http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/datepicker/images/calendar.gif ",
  buttonImageOnly: true,
  buttonText: "Select date",
  defaultDate: "+1w",
  changeMonth: true,
  changeYear: true,
  numberOfMonths: 1,
  onClose: function(selectedDate) {
    $("#from").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<form>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <input class="filtertype" type="radio" name="filtertype" checked="checked" value="bydate">
      </th>
      <th>By Date</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label>Form</label>
        <input class="filtertypeinput" id="from">
      </td>
      <td>
        <label>To</label>
        <input class="filtertypeinput" id="to">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <input class="filtertype" type="radio" name="filtertype" value="byyear">
      </th>
      <th>By Year</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">
        <select class="filtertypeinput" disabled="disabled">
          <option value="">Please select</option>
          <option>test 1</option>
          <option>test 2</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="2">Report</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">
        <select id="report" name="report">
          <option value="">Please Select</option>
          <option value="Company">Company</option>
          <option value="MyExportAccount">MyExport Account</option>
          <option value="Sectors">Sectors</option>
          <option value="States">States</option>
          <option value="ExportStatus">Export Status</option>
          <option value="BusinessType">Business Type</option>
          <option value="MobileApp">Mobile App</option>
          <option value="Login">Login</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Please consider including some information about your answer, rather than simply posting code. We try to provide not just 'fixes', but help people learn. You should explain what was wrong in the original code, what you did differently, and why your change(s) worked.

Answer (score 0):

The most up-voted solution did not work for me. I have date pickers with default of disabled, which works fine. When it comes time to enable them in the **window.onload** function, though, the **$("#award_start_date").datepicker( 'enable' );** syntax did not enable the widgets. I was able to edit the field as if it were a text input field, but did not get the calendar chooser.

What does work is this:

```
if (x[i].id == "award_start_date") {
  $("#award_start_date").datepicker( {enabled: true} );
}
if (x[i].id == "award_end_date") {
  $("#award_end_date").datepicker( {enabled: true} );
}
```

It may be that this simply recreates the datepickers, but for my purposes, that is fine.

This is my second day using jQuery UI awesomeness, so I may be missing some of the finer points...

Answer (score 0):

```
   $("#datepicker").datepicker({
     dateFormat:'dd/M/yy',
     minDate: 'now',
     changeMonth:true,
     changeYear:true,
     showOn: "focus",
    // buttonImage: "YourImage",
     buttonImageOnly: true, 
     yearRange: "-100:+0",  
  }); 

  $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( "option", "disabled", true ); //missing ID selector
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this it will help you

```
$("#from").click(function () {
           $('#from').attr('readonly', true);
     });
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Top answer doesnt work for jquery-ui calendar and answer below disables all inputs on page:

`$("input").prop('disabled', true);`

which can be avoided by specifying the datepicker id:

`$("input#from").prop('disabled', true);`

Answer (score -1):

try this :

```
$("#form").datetimepicker("disable");
```

Answer (score -1):

You can replace form field with its copy:

`var copy = $('#from').clone();
 $('#from').replaceWith(copy);`

And after that initialize datetimepicker again.

Comment: I think you left out some quotation marks here:  var copy = $('#from').clone(); $('#from').replaceWith(copy);