# Disabling datepicker on an input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

Cuurently I have an input field using `datepicker`. I am wondering how to disable the datepicker callendar popping up when I click on that field, since on my page I want the date option to be available only on certain conditions.

```
<input id="date" type="text " class="form-control datepicker" name="date" value="Click to select date">
```

I tried with  :

```
 $("#date").datepicker('disable');
```

And with :

```
$( "#date" ).datepicker( "disabled", true );
```

None worked.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery: enabling/disabling datepicker](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18350923/jquery-enabling-disabling-datepicker)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the easiest way is to remove all the pointer events for that input field.

```
$("#date").css('pointer-events', 'none');
```

This will keep the data intact if you want.

And to re enable pointer events.

```
   $("#date").css("pointer-events", "");
```

Comment: Thanks. And how can I enable them back ? :)

Comment: This is really a workaround, it will also entirely disable clicking that input to begin with... @RobertRoss look at the duplicate question

Comment: I tried all of the answers, @casraf. Nothing worked, probably it's something with my code.

Comment: What datepicker library are you using? The regular jQuery UI's one?

Comment: @casraf - yes, i am using this.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be working:

```
$('#date').datepicker('option', 'disabled', t_or_f)
```

Working example:

```js
function toggleDatePicker (state) {
  // this actually does the magic
  $('#date').datepicker('option', 'disabled', !state)
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  // init
  $('#date').datepicker();

  
  // ignore this, just for the sake of example
  $('#butt').on('click', function() {
    var st = parseInt($(this).data('state'));
    $(this).data('state', st = 1 - st); // toggle 0 and 1
    $(this).text(st ? 'Disable' : 'Enable');
    toggleDatePicker(Boolean(st));
  });
});
```

```css
@import url(https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<input id="date" type="text " class="form-control datepicker" name="date" value="Click to select date">

<button id="butt" data-state="1">Disable</button>
```