# jQuery Date Picker - disable all end dates if user has not select start date

Tags: jquery, datepicker

In My date picker I have certain constraints

1. End date should not be earlier than Start date -Done
2. Now my problem is User should not able to select End date without selecting the Start date

My Jquery for datepicker:

```
var dateToday = new Date(); 
$( function() {
  $( "#datepicker1" ).datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    dateFormat:'dd-M-yy',
    //   minDate: dateToday,
    onClose: function (selected) {
      $("#end").datepicker("option", "minDate", selected);
    }
  });
  $( "#end" ).datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    dateFormat:'dd-M-yy',
    // minDate: dateToday,
    onClose: function (selected) {
      $("#datepicker1").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selected);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery: enabling/disabling datepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18350923/jquery-enabling-disabling-datepicker)

Comment: Thank you so much for your  reply , how to use that without affecting my previous code

Comment: Just disable the second datepicker by default and enable within `onClose` event handler of the first datepicker if a date value has been selected.

Comment: Ya I have disabled initially , but i could not able to enable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the changes in:

```
onClose: function (selected) {
  if(selected.length <= 0) {
      // selected is empty
      $("#end").datepicker('disable')
  } else {
      $("#end").datepicker('enable');
  }
  $("#end").datepicker("option", "minDate", selected);
}
```

Demo here to give you an idea. Adopt to your needs.

```js
var dateToday = new Date(); 
$( function() {
  $( "#datepicker1" ).datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    dateFormat:'dd-M-yy',
    //   minDate: dateToday,
    onClose: function (selected) {
      if(selected.length <= 0) {
          // selected is empty
          $("#end").datepicker('disable');
      } else {
          $("#end").datepicker('enable');
      }
      $("#end").datepicker("option", "minDate", selected);
    }
  });
  $( "#end" ).datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    dateFormat:'dd-M-yy',
    // minDate: dateToday,
    onClose: function (selected) {
      if(selected.length <= 0) {
          // selected is empty
          $("#datepicker1").datepicker('disable');
      } else {
          $("#datepicker1").datepicker('enable');
      }
      $("#datepicker1").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selected);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datepicker/0.6.4/datepicker.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>



<input id="datepicker1" type="text">
<input id="end" type="text">
```

Comment: Thank you so much its Working Perfectly

Comment: Oh, your answer is faster and better ;)

Answer (score 1):

In first you should disable the `#end` datepicker by default. Then modify the `onClick` handler of the `#datepicker1` as following:

```
onClose: function (selected) { 
  $("#end")
    .datepicker("option", "minDate", selected)
    .datepicker("option", "disabled", !selected);
}
```

Comment: Working perfect, If i select start date then only my end date is enabling, Once i choose both , I am deleting the start date now the end date is disabling again but its containing the latest chosen value

Comment: @Vishnu , I forget the start date may be removed. I have updated the code to lock end datepicker again when start date will be removed.