# datepicker onload() to set minDate and maxDate doesnt work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker

Simply put, the following syntax doesnt work

```
onload="$(this).datepicker('option', {minDate: -0, maxDate: +0})"
```

which i have used in the input for a form as given below

```
<input type="text" name="date" class="datepicker form-control" onload="$(this).datepicker('option', {minDate: -0, maxDate: +0})" autocomplete="off"/>
```

What I want is for not being able to select a date at initial page load but later enabling it after a certain option is selected. Am i missing something that i cant see? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: $(element).data('DateTimePicker').minDate(date);

Comment: $(window).load(function(){
    $('.dateField').val('');
})

Comment: Maybe you want to disable datepicker at initial page load and then enable?... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18350923/jquery-enabling-disabling-datepicker

Comment: Thanks for the help but these solutions do not seem to work.