# Django / JQuery - Changing JQuery calendar based on DB data

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django, model

As a part of a task, I created an "apartment listings" website. I managed to get that done, but now I need to make a "reservation system" for it.
The basic idea is that a logged in user can select an apartment from the listed apartments, pick a "start_date" and an "end_date" (if the apartment already isn't booked ) and book the apartment.

When the user clicks on the date input field, a jquery datepicker pops up and he can then pick the date via the calendar, same for end date.
Once he goes through with the booking, I want the dates to be "disabled" in the calendar so no one else can pick them.

This is the datepicker that I'm using:

```
https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/
```

and the code:

```
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#datepicker").datepicker();
        });
    </script>
```

Im a total Django / web development newbie, and need some pointers in order to start somewhere with this task, I know some JS but jquery is new to me, that's why I'd like some help.

I have an Apartment model which contains all of the Apartments info that I use to print everything out with the template.
I have an Reservation model which saves the start date and end date of the booking to the db.

I'm using the provided django user models to register / log-in.
I’m using Django 2.1.8 (mySQL db)

I have created this view  and model to make my reservations :

single listing view:

```py
def apartment_view(request, apartment_id):

    reservation_pk = request.GET.get('pk', None)
    reservation = Reservation.objects.filter(apartment__pk=apartment_id)
    apartment = get_object_or_404(Apartment, pk=apartment_id)
    context = {'apartment': apartment, }
    context_instance = RequestContext(request)

    form = ReservationForm()
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = ReservationForm()

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        form = ReservationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            reservation = form.save(commit=False)
            reservation.apartment = apartment
            reservation.save()
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/booking/')
    args = {}
    args['form'] = form
    args['apartment'] = context
    args['reservation'] = reservation
    return render(request, 'booking/apartment.html', args)
```

models:

```py
class Apartment(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    zipcode = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    bedrooms = models.IntegerField()
    bathrooms = models.DecimalField(max_digits=2, decimal_places=1)
    garage = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    size = models.IntegerField()
    photo_main = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/')
    photo_1 = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True)
    photo_2 = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True)
    photo_3 = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True)
    photo_4 = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True)
    in_rent = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    list_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Reservation(models.Model):
    apartment = models.ForeignKey(Apartment, related_name='reservations',
                                  on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    start_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True, unique=True)
    end_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(default="", max_length=200, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "Reservation"
```

my form:

```py
class ReservationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Reservation
        fields = [
            'start_date',
            'end_date',
            'name',
        ]
        widgets = {
            'start_date': TextInput(attrs={'id': 'datepicker'}),
            'end_date': TextInput(attrs={'id': 'datepicker2'}),
        }
```

Thank you for the time you took to read this, and for your help !
Have a good day guys !

TLDR : Based on data from db I need to "disable" certain date ranges in the jquery calendar

Comment: You can refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18350923/jquery-enabling-disabling-datepicker for disabling the datepicker

Comment: That is not what I am asking , sorry if it's confusing.
I need a way to disable DATES in the calendar, so I need the calendar to "look" at the Reservations model, and "disable" or gray out all the dates in it.

Comment: you mean you want to show the calendar but disable selection of dates from it?

Comment: Yes, that is correct ! I need to query from db and based on the data disable selection for the dates that came back !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of `beforeShowDay` function parameter to disable the dates.

Please check **[JQuery UI Datepicker API](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/)** for more information

```js
$(function () {
        $('.pickWeek').datepicker({
           beforeShowDay : function (date) {return [false, '',''];}
        })
    });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  
  <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" class="pickWeek"></p>
```