# Make bootstrap datepicker disabled from button

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I have created form with lot of data inside. I have button that i use to disable fields inside the form. Everything works great but i have no idea what to do with timepickers

I have multiple datepickers and i want to disable them all.

Here is part of code what i've done for this:

```
$("#object-form").on("click mousedown mouseup onkeydown",  select, textarea, .date", function (evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    evt.stopPropagation();
    return false;
});
```

But for datepickers these approach doesn't work.

Here is simple html for my datepicker:

```
<div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
    <input type='text' class="form-control" />
    <span class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
    </span>
</div>

<div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker2'>
    <input type='text' class="form-control" />
    <span class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
    </span>
</div>

<button onclick='DisableThem()'>Disable datepickers</button>
```

What should i write in DisableThem() to make my code work?

Comment: Have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18350923/jquery-enabling-disabling-datepicker

Answer (score 0):

**Selector Issue:**

> `.date` is the selector for div, not for the .
>   For this case only, you may use `.form-control` or add your own selector.

```
$("#object-form").on("click mousedown mouseup onkeydown",  select, textarea, .date", function (evt) {
                evt.preventDefault();
                evt.stopPropagation();
                return false;
            });
```

Feel free to ask, if you need more clarification.